# Prevent iPhone timepicker

Tags: cordova

I am using this [time picker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) because I need to choose minutes & seconds and the iPhone time picker, which pops up automatically for a 'time' input, only provides a minute/hour control. How do I prevent the native time picker from popping up as well when I use a jquery timepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$('input[type="time"]').bind('focus', function(e) {e.preventDefault(); });

Comment: Thanks, Menno, but seems to make no difference. I have tried this line both after the document is opened and just before the timepicker is called.